# Does $S\subset R$ imply $A\otimes_{R} A \subset A\otimes_{S} A$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, tensors, quotient-group

I'm currently trying to prove Proposition 3.2 from the paper "*Galois correspondence for Hopf Bigalois Extensions*" by Peter Schauenburg, focusing on the last two implications it declares as "clear". The details of the proof are irrelevant, I just assumed something that now I'm not sure if holds:

> Let $A$ be an $R$-module, and let $S\subset R$ ($A$ is also an
> $S$-module). Then $A\otimes_RA\subset A\otimes_S A$.

Does that "$\subset$" make sense? Or should it be "*$A\otimes_RA$ is a quotient of $A\otimes_S A$*"? If not, is there any relation I can find between two ordered sets $S\subset R$ and their corresponding $\otimes_S$, $\otimes_R$? Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R$ be a ring, $M$ a right $R$-module, and $N$ a left $R$-module. The usual construction of the tensor product $M \otimes_R N$ is that we take the free abelian group on $M \times N$ and quotient by the minimum relations necessary for bilinearity: for all $m, m' \in M$, $r \in R$, and $n, n' \in N$,

- $(m, n + n') - (m, n) - (m, n') = 0$,
- $(m + m', n) - (m, n) - (m', n) = 0$,
- $(m \cdot r, n) - (m, r \cdot n) = 0$.

If $S \subseteq R$ is a subring, then $M \otimes_S N$ is constructed as the quotient of the same free abelian group by the same relations, except the last set of relations is smaller because we are only quantifying over all $r \in S$ rather than all $r \in R$. Thus, $M \otimes_R N$ is a quotient of $M \otimes_S N$. (You can also deduce this from the universal properties, but I think it's a little easier to see this from the construction.)